# Does a StatefulSet pod, when deleted or failed, get redeployed on the same worker node, or is it deployed on another available worker node?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-statefulset, cri-o

Does a StatefulSet pod, when deleted or failed, get redeployed on the same worker node, or is it deployed on another available worker node?

Seeking clarification on the default behavior of StatefulSet pods in Kubernetes when they are deleted or failed whether they are rescheduled on the same worker node or on different worker nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, k8s will schedule a new pod on any 1 of the nodes which has sufficient CPU and memory resources available. If you specified any special conditions like Pod affinity, Pod affinity or Node affinity, k8s will follow them accordingly. Please check out this official [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)